# How to get deep links to work in Angular when deployed in Http Server

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am making a blog site with Angular. Angular routes are configured in a way where "localhost:4200/post/42" will navigate to a post component where I fetch post description from a MySql database based on id provided in the url e.g. 42 in this case. It works fine in development mode. But when I am deploying it in an apache2 web server hosted in Digital Ocean, the routes don't work when I directly post the link ("www.my-domain.com/post/42") in the browser.  It gives a 404 error. I can configure the .htaccess file and redirect to index.html page, but that is not serving my purpose. If someone posts the blog url in social network then people clicking the link won't bring them to the particular blog post, instead it will take them to the home component.

Is there a solution to this problem? When developers make websites with Angular how do they tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) by adding `{ useHash: true }` in your RouterModule forRoot function like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
```

Another way (Recommended) is to leave it with default *PathLocationStrategy* and use `base-href="./"` with your build like this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href="./"
```

Read [LocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) for more details.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. The HashLocationStrategy worked. But unfortunately the base-href="./" is not working.  Do I have to do anything other then just running the command ng build --prod --base-href="./" ?

Comment: It should work. Copying from [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#html5-urls-and-the--base-href): *Without that tag, the browser may not be able to load resources (images, CSS, scripts) when "deep linking" into the app. Bad things could happen when someone pastes an application link into the browser's address bar or clicks such a link in an email.*

Comment: in the providers array i have entered {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy} and in index.html i have set the   <base href="./">

After deploying the app in the server if i go to the url www.my-domain.com/post/42, i again get the 404 error

Comment: You don't need to add the PathLocationStrategy, it is the default value. I'm checking why this strategy is not working for you... I'll update if I'll have news

Comment: sure. thanks. I did some more digging. I found out the only solution for my problem is using Angular Universal Server side rendering.

Comment: You are right, this will work for you. But didn't you said that HashLocationStrategy  is working for you?

Comment: yes hashLocationStrategy is working. But I have heard that it's bad for SEO.